# How can I relay a SMS with Twilio?

Tags: twilio

I am trying to understand if the API allows me to receive a SMS at my Twilio number and then relay that message out to a different non-Twilio number. If so how do I setup the app / API to do this? Sorry but at a total loss where to start with this one.

SMS to Twilio >>> Twilio >>>> Non Twilio Number

Comment: What have you tried? What language are you using? Desktop or Web? Read the rules before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

I'd suggest starting by walking through our SMS quickstarts.  This will get you familiar with how to receive an SMS message to your Twilio phone number, and also how to send them using the REST API.

I'll link you to the PHP version of the quickstarts, but they are available in 5 different programming languages:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms

Hope that helps.